# How to clone from master, thereby updating by remote branch as well as my local directories?

Tags: git, gitlab

Being new to git I'am a little confused, a `git clone` gets you the latest code from the master repository to the local system, but I have a branch say `x`, if that is not updated like the local system, will that result in conflict when i later push from local to branch. If yes, then how do i clone properly?

I have tried a `git clone <master>`, but not sure is the branch `x` also getting updated.

Comment: Just update your local branch with `git pull`, no?

Answer (score 1):

First, welcome with Git :-) You seem to have a bit of a confusion between branches and repositories.

`git clone` will allow you to create a new copy of an existing repository on your computer.

The syntax is: `git clone <path/or/url/of/the/repository>` not `git clone <branch-name>` as you seem to be confused.

So, yes when you will clone, you will get the latest code from the master *branch* in your local repository, from the *remote* repository.

At this point, your local copy of the project knows that on the remote it's been cloned from (named `origin`), there is another branch `x`. At this point, if you create modifications and commit on your local `master`, and then push it, it will update the remote `master` branch, but `x` will stay unchanged.

If you want to bring changes to `x`, you will first need to do a `checkout` (`git checkout x`), this will change the state of your local files to be with the changes which occurred with the commits in `x`. You can then change the files, commit them, and push, which will update the remote `x`.

If you want to get the latest changes of a remote branch to your local clone, you have two cases:
Either the branch does not exist locally, and then you just need to `git checkout thebranch` which will create it locally, at the state it is on the remote.

Or the branch exist locally and is out of date. In which case, you first need to "be on it" (`git checkout thebranch`), and then pull the latest version: `git pull`.

Git will not know automatically if changes occurred remotely. You need to manually update you remotes manually to check for changes with `git remote update`, which *update* your knowledge of the state of the *remotes* repositories.

Comment: As an alternative to `git remote update` to get fresh references from your main remote, let's not forget the simple `git fetch`. Excellent answer anyway, I had one half way through but this is better than what I had so far.

Comment: Yes definitely for `git fetch`. `git remote update` is just an alias/sugaring of `git fetch`, that I find a bit more semantically clear than fetch, also, by default it would fetch all remotes (in case there are more than one).

Comment: Is it so? I was under the impression that `git fetch` gets the refs from all *branches*, but defaults to `origin` when the remote is not explicitly given. But it doesn't fetch from all *remotes*, does it? This is `--all` option's job.

Comment: you can use the `--all` option in `git fetch` to fetch them all (cf `man git-fetch`).

Comment: Yes that's *my* point :-) but didn't you say that by default it fetches all remotes? Oh I get it, you refered to `git remote update`? Stupid confusion on my part ^^

Comment: sorry, I miss expressed myself, I meant:  `git remote update` is just an alias/sugaring of `git fetch`, that I find a bit more semantically clear than fetch. Also, by default `git remote update` would fetch all remotes (in case there are more than one), which `git fetch` does not.